# Django Message Inbox

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm pretty new on Django. I'm just trying to create a messaging app and i want to make a conversation inbox. To explain a little more there are two users like user1 and user2. I need to classify conversation between user1 and user2 also user2 and user3. Then I can get conversations with DRF to React. I looked up [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526911/how-to-show-the-last-message-of-each-user-to-user-conversations-to-keep-a-chat-h) but I'm so confused. I think on generate conversation ID for this. But I don't know how to do this.

[image: I don't want to this]

A part of JSON output (Conversation between same users):

```
{
 "sender": 1,
 "reciever": 2,
 "msg_content": "Bu da benim yanıtım.",
 "sendtime": "2021-05-27T10:44:10.722370Z"
  },
 {
  "sender": 2,
  "reciever": 1,
  "msg_content": "Eh, yeter!",
  "sendtime": "2021-05-27T10:44:19.074474Z"
  },
```

I don't know how to get rid of this issue. For example you are messaging on Whatsapp with Alex and your name is Joseph. It should be just one conversation on your App's homescreen but there is two conversation. One is shows your last message to Alex and another one is Alex's last message.

**models.py**

```
 class Message(models.Model):
         sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_query_name='s')
         reciever = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="reciever", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_query_name='r')
         msg_content = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
         sendtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class MessagesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        connected_user = self.request.user
        queryset = Message.objects \
            .filter(Q(sender=self.request.user) | Q(reciever=self.request.user)) \
            .order_by('sender', 'reciever', '-sendtime') \
            .distinct('sender', 'reciever')
        if (1==1):
                return queryset
```

**serializers.py**

```
   class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Message
            fields = ('id', 'sender','reciever','msg_content','sendtime')
```